# Error con la ejecución de un archivo usando "os.system()" debido a los acentos en la ruta del archivo

Tags: python

Básicamente, es esto lo que ocurre.

El código es algo parecido a esto:

```
import os

os.system(r"python C:\Users\User\Desktop\Información de ejemplo\prueba.py")
```

Y la salida del error es el siguiente:

```
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Informaci├│n': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

¿Qué se puede hacer para que no haya problemas a la hora de poner cualquier ruta, tenga acentos o no?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: es mala practica tener acentos en las rutas de los directorios, elimina los acentos en los directorio de desarrollo... https://realpython.com/python-encodings-guide/

Comment: Si te limitas al ASCII, nunca tendras problemas en ninguna platforma.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de python usas? (Mírate https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/os.html#python-utf-8-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es bastante sencilla. Consiste en usar comillas en la ruta de acceso al archivo.

#### Esta es la ruta que usas en tu código

```
ruta = r"python C:\Users\User\Desktop\Información de ejemplo\prueba.py"
```

Para solucionarlo sigue estos simples pasos:

1. Usa comillas simples para toda la cadena de texto:
2. Usa comillas dobles para la ruta del archivo

#### Ruta corregida

```
ruta = r'python "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Información de ejemplo\prueba.py"'
```

#### Así quedaría todo el código corregido

```
import os
ruta = r'python "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Información de ejemplo\prueba.py"'
os.system(ruta)
```

Recuerda que es muy recomendable **NO** usar acentos en los nombres de las carpetas.
Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!!!!! Los acentos son "exigencias" y ojalá pudiera seguir tu consejo, pero en el trabajo hay veces que no puedes aconsejar :/ jajaja (Siento la demora en responder y darte el visto bueno)